# Suggestions for In-browser word editing

Tags: java, cross-browser, ms-word, cross-platform

I work at a transcription company that stores physician's transcriptions on a central file server. Users are able to access our website and open up the transcription (a .doc file) to view, edit, e-sign, print, ect.

Currently, when the user goes to open the document, it uses a Java application and the local computer's Microsoft Word to open an instance of the document. Currently there are limitations to the application though.

1. Only Windows OS compatible (due to the Java COM operation)
2. Only 32-bit Java compatible
3. Difficult to replicate for mobile application

My question was, is it possible to have an in-browser editor, with the functionality of Word, that is able to pull and open Microsoft Word documents from a file server and allow users to make edits and save them across Windows and Apple OS, with possible mobile app integration as well?
A friend at Google suggested using Google Docs, which would require google accounts and a BA agreement, creating a little too much work on the client side. Any suggestions would help.
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe. If you were in the LA area at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Of course a native docx editor would be best, however, you can convert to XHTML, edit with CKEditor, then convert back to docx.

[This blog post of mine](http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2014/09/xhtml-docx-roundtrip-content-tracking/) ignores the details/intricacies involved in doing that, instead jumping ahead to explain how to track content through that process.